# How to create OPOS Service Objects for Serial Port - Weighing Scale

Tags: c#, serial-port, point-of-sale, opos

I'm having a **weighing scale**. The vendor does not have **OPOS service object implementation** for the device. somehow, I'm able to implement read weight from serial port but I want to implement OPOS service object for reading weight and publish it for POS systems.
I'm at very beginner level stage for this and it will require a brief help for implementing this.

Comment: I was working on an OPOS Service Object project several months ago which I put on the back burner. It is in C++ and I think that it is primarily the skeleton for a Service Object. If I remember correctly, the skeleton would start and run and generate logs as I exercised it. However it does not actually do anything as that was the next phase which I never got to.  You are welcome to take a look at the source as it currently exists. https://github.com/RichardChambers/atl_msr_so

Comment: Actually I solved it myself before few days. The hardware that the client has purchased was low cost which was not OPOS compliant and I wanted to make that OPOS compliant. So I fake the OPOS service object and hard coded some of properties and methods to return exact behavior. On Read event, I code for serial port to read the weight and that worked. We made the project live last week and the client is happy so am I. BTW, I developed this in C#. It was quite easy while implementing but hard when searching for help online.

Comment: I am glad that you were able to work out something. You are correct that searching for help online provides very little assistance on OPOS though I did find a book. I started this project due to lack of OPOS support for an MSR on a terminal with the intention of learning low level USB in addition to OPOS Service Object. USB protocols seems to be a specialized and complicated area and then I was involved with Out of Scope approaches instead with PAA-DSS considerations and EMV support needed. However your question led me to consider a scale interface Service Object using Serial interface.